# push view when touchesBegan

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a apps with a navigation controller, when the user is in a specific view, He can touch a scollview and I want a push the rootViewController. So, I have subclasses uiscrollview, and in the method "touchesBegan", I want a push the rootviewcontroller, but I don't have access to the navigation controller! How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your subclass of UIScrollView create two instance variables:

```
id delegate;
SEL touchAction;
```

Then create methods:

```
-(void)setTarget:(id)target andAction:(SEL)action {
    delegate = target;
    touchAction = action;
}
-(void)callAction {
    if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:touchAction]) {
        [delegate performSelector:touchAction];
    }
}
```

In your touchesBegan just call this method:

```
...
[self callAction];
...
```

In your UIViewController class create method:

```
-(void)myScrollViewTouchAction {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myNewViewController animated:YES];
}
```

and finally when creating instance of your UIScrollView subclass, set it target and action:

```
[myScrollView setTarget:self andAction:@selector(myScrollViewTouchAction)];
```

Comment: I do all this things but when this line is executed: [delegate performSelector:touchAction], the method myScrollViewTouchAction is not called, in the initwithnibname of my view controller, i create a instance of the uiscrollview subclass and I call setTarget....

Comment: The problem is that when I called setTarget and when touchesBegan is called, it's not the same object, so the delegate is not set when the touchesBegan is called...

Comment: then set target and action for new object.

Answer (score 1):

UIViewControllers have a property "navigationController", so you just need to access the view controller of the view being touched.

However, I've found that in iphone development, jumping through hoops like that is a sign of weakness in development.  For example, why should a view tell a view CONTROLLER to do something.  It should be the other way around.  That being said, UIViewController is a subclass of UIResponder, so you can handle touches in the controller.  Then you can simply say.

[myViewController.navigationController pushViewController:animated:]